# Android: MotionEvent.obtain with webview does not work

Tags: android, webview, touch-event, motionevent

I have a question about the MotionEvent in Android. I want to sent a "Click" to a Webview because there is an iframe and i have to click an Image/Button, which is in the iframe. So I can´t you js because I can not control the content of the iframe.

My Code:

```
private void simulateDoubleTapEvent(int action)
{
    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
    float x = 35.407104f;
    float y = 378.52066f;
    // List of meta states found here: developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getMetaState()
    int metaState = 0;
    MotionEvent me = MotionEvent.obtain(
        downTime, 
        eventTime, 
        action, 
        x, 
        y, 
        metaState
    );
    dispatchTouchEvent(me);
}
```

And in onCreate:

```
webview2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
              int action = event.getAction();
               float x = event.getX();
               float y = event.getY();
                         event.getMetaState();
               Log.v("ON_TOUCH", "Action = " + action + " View:" + v.toString());
               Log.v("ON_TOUCH", "X = " + x + "Y = " + y);


           return false;
           }
   });
   webview2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override 
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
    { view.loadUrl(url); return true; }
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.w("webview2","Load");

        simulateDoubleTapEvent(0);
                simulateDoubleTapEvent(1);
    }
   });
```

The webView Load the Url, but the Code does not Click on it. If I click on the webView the onTouch Event is fired.

Can you please help me?

Best greetings form Germany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the webview as argument to your simulateDoubleTapEvent() method and use it for dispatching.

```
private void simulateDoubleTapEvent(WebView view, int action)
{
    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
    float x = 35.407104f;
    float y = 378.52066f;
    // List of meta states found here: developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getMetaState()
    int metaState = 0;
    MotionEvent me = MotionEvent.obtain(
        downTime, 
        eventTime, 
        action, 
        x, 
        y, 
        metaState
    );
    view.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
}
```